# why i have error during the installation of eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When i try to install the eclipse, the error pop out. i dont know why.

```
    [2021-04-16 10:26:21] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 HTTP Server 'Service Unavailable': http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2021-03/202103121200/content.jar
    ERROR: org.eclipse.ecf.identity code=0 HttpComponents connection error response code 503.
      at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45.HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.openStreams(HttpClientRetrieveFileTransfer.java:616)
      at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.sendRetrieveRequest(AbstractRetrieveFileTransfer.java:887)
    at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.retrieve.MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.sendRetrieveRequest(MultiProtocolRetrieveAdapter.java:148)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.sendRetrieveRequest(FileReader.java:454)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.FileReader.readInto(FileReader.java:384)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.RepositoryTransport.download(RepositoryTransport.java:107)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.download(CachingTransport.java:193)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingTransport.download(CachingTransport.java:256)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.updateCache(CacheManager.java:404)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.CacheManager.createCache(CacheManager.java:263)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.getLocalFile(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:69)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.load(SimpleMetadataRepositoryFactory.java:89)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.factoryLoad(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:63)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.helpers.AbstractRepositoryManager.loadRepository(AbstractRepositoryManager.java:775)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.util.ReflectUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectUtil.java:119)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:423)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:214)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.CachingRepositoryManager$Metadata.loadRepository(CachingRepositoryManager.java:495)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:110)
      at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.metadata.repository.MetadataRepositoryManager.loadRepository(MetadataRepositoryManager.java:105)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl$RepositoryLoader$Worker.perform(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:1578)
      at org.eclipse.oomph.util.WorkerPool$Worker.run(WorkerPool.java:434)
      at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
    
    [2021-04-16 10:26:21]
```

this is the latest version that i try to install. i've downloaded it on `eclipse.org` site.

Comment: It might be a temporary server outage (see: https://www.eclipsestatus.io/), your proxy, if you are behind one, or something in between.